# Ошибка в откр. файла. Пишет, что нету такого файла

Tags: python

```
import re


input_file = open('progr.txt', 'r')
resultfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
mytext = input_file.read()

results = re.sub(r"<!-.*?->", '', mytext)
resultfile.write(results)

input_file.close()
resultfile.close()
```

Comment: очевидно текущая директория скрипта не та, которую вы ожидаете. Укажите полный путь к файлам или явно смените директорию в скрипте: `os.chdir(".....")`

Comment: Импортируйте библиотеку **os** import os

Comment: ' ', а для чего нужны эти лапки, пустые?

Comment: не совсем понял, вы спрашиваете о собственном коде из вопроса?

Comment: re.sub('что ищем', 'на что заменяем', 'где все это ищем') вы про это?

Answer (score 4):

Такого файла нет в директории из которой запущен скрипт и это не одно и тоже с директорией где скрипт расположен.
Попробуйте так:

```py
import re
import os

# Получить текущую директорию, где расположен скрипт
dr = os.path.abspath(__file__)
path, file = os.path.split(dr)
path += os.path.join(path + "\\")

input_file = open(path + 'progr.txt', 'r')
resultfile = open(path + 'result.txt', 'w')
mytext = input_file.read()

results = re.sub(r"<!-.*?->", '', mytext)
resultfile.write(results)

input_file.close()
resultfile.close()
```

Или тоже самое через pathlib

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path 

DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

input_file = open(DIR / 'progr.txt', 'r')
resultfile = open(DIR / 'result.txt', 'w')
mytext = input_file.read()

results = re.sub(r"<!-.*?->", '', mytext)
resultfile.write(results)

input_file.close()
resultfile.close()
```

Comment: для конкатенации путей лучше использовать `os.path.join()`

Comment: Или вместо `os.path` использовать пакет `pathlib`. Тогда, чтобы получить текущую директорию нужно: `from pathlib import Path` + `DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent`, а чтобы составить путь до файлов: `DIR / 'progr.txt'` и `DIR / 'result.txt'` и

Comment: Добавил Ваш вариант. Он требует меньше действий.